# userNotificationCenter:didReceiveNotificationResponse:withCompletionHandler: is not fired

Tags: objective-c-runtime

Able to receive  the notification but delegate method is not fired after clicking on the notification.

Note :

UNUserNotificationCenter delegate received call to -userNotificationCenter:didReceiveNotificationResponse:withCompletionHandler: but the completion handler was never called.

Comment: Really it is a blocker for me , not sure exactly where i am doing wrong.

Comment: Add some more code.

Comment: I have the same issue with swift